# How to clear environment variable suggested by Jasypt Java library?

Tags: java, process, environment-variables, jasypt

One way Jasypt recommends to pass the master key to a Java Application is through an [environment variable](http://www.jasypt.org/advancedconfiguration.html).

In that webpage, jasypt proposes that:

> This will allow the user, for example, to set an encryption password in an environment variable, start the application or application server, let the jasypt encryptor object initialise, and then unset the variable (thus hiding it)

How can I accomplish the "unset the variable" part?

Comment: You can't. Suggest you put password in a file, and read the file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, basically Jasypt offers a Spring integration  that is not secure? Seems like Jasypt-Spring should offer file-based approach, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following @Andreas suggestion, that is, read the master key from a file (which ideally should have restrictive permissions.)

In order to keep the advantage of Jasypt Spring integration, I made a custom "FilePBEConfig":

```
package com.my.product;

import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FilePBEConfig extends SimplePBEConfig {
    private String passwordFilePath = null;

    public FilePBEConfig() {
        super();
    }

    public String getPasswordFilePath() {
        return passwordFilePath;
    }

    public void setPasswordFilePath(final String passwordFilePath) throws IOException {
        this.passwordFilePath = passwordFilePath;
        if (passwordFilePath == null) {
            super.setPassword(null);
        } else {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(passwordFilePath))) {
                super.setPassword(br.readLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which then you can use it in your Spring xml file as suggested by [Jasypt Spring Integration](http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html):

```
 <bean id="fileConfiguration"
     class="com.my.product.FilePBEConfig">
   <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
   <property name="passwordFilePath" value="/path/to/masterfile" />
 </bean>
```